# How to suppress oscillations of the LC circuit current?

Tags: power-electronics, control, pid-controller, oscillation

I have a following circuit

[image]

which basically consists of three individual power electronics converters

- **Converter_01**

In case \$v_1 > v_2\$ it operates as a single phase diode bridge rectifier according to the polarity of the dc voltage \$v_1\$. In case \$v_2 > v_1 + \Delta v\$ the transistors T1+T2 or T3+T4 are turned on according to the polarity of the input voltage. The turn on signals are produced by a control software.

- **Converter_02**

Its goal is to prevent \$v_2\$ to exceed \$v_{2_{ref}}\$ level. This goal is achieved via pwm switching of the T5 with a duty cycle calculated by the \$R_{v_2}\$ controller (simple PI controller) implemented in a control software. It is worthwhile to say that this converter basically works as a \$v_2\$ limiter.

- **Converter_03**

Basically a source of the dc current charging the common capacity C.

I have been struggling with oscillations of the \$i_L\$ in a situation when the transistors T1+T2 or T3+T4 (depending on the polarity of the input voltage \$v_1\$) are turned on. The oscillations occur with resonant frequency of the LC filter i.e.
\$f_r = \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{L\cdot C}} = \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{490\cdot 10^{-6}\cdot 2700\cdot 10^{-6}}} 
\sim 138\,\mathrm{Hz}\$. What I have been looking for is a mechanism how to suppress those oscillations in the set up described above. Does anybody have any idea how to do that?

Comment: Please use larger font size or a higher resolution; several labels are unreadable. What is the underlying purpose of this system? What are the inputs and outputs? It's not clear what you're trying to do other than make an oscillator...

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you for your reaction. I have just attempted to improve the readability of the diagram. The underlying purpose of this system is an electrical drive with the ability to recuperate energy into the dc source.

Comment: Okay but, drive *what*? Why does it need to recuperate energy? (Why can it apparently sometimes recuperate too much thus needing an overvoltage or braking resistor?) Is it supposed to drive a particular waveform, or present some impedance to the load?  I guess the load is V1 then ("load" in the functional sense, regardless of whether it can also source power from time to time). This is starting to sound like a bog standard PMAC motor drive (possibly 1ph BLDC given the mere H-bridge?); you don't need to be cagey about that, there's nothing important to hide here...

Comment: It is a three phase induction motor based drive on a testbench. The three phase voltage source inverter is modeled as a current source in the Converter_3 box.

Comment: As far as the requirement for energy recuperation. It is for energy saving purposes. The \$v_1\$ voltage is in fact voltage provided by the the three phase active front end which is capable to return the energy into the three phase utility grid with unity power factor.

Comment: @TimWilliams is it more clear now or shall I explain anything?